# Fazer um DIV aparecer somente em um determinado horário

Tags: php, html, div

Por exemplo, tenho uma determinada div, mas quero que ela apareça somente das 18 horas as 00 horas de todos os dias, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <h1>aqui vai o conteudo da div</h1>
</div>
```

Quero que essa div apareça somente no horário determinado, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Desculpa, mas e que não entendi aonde editar o $horainicio, eu substituo ou crio uma nova string ?

Comment: Não esqueça de acertar a hora do servidor para o fuso correto do horário desejado.

Comment: Eu usei $horaatual = date('H:i:s' );

Comment: verifique o horário do lado server e adicione `display` no div quando desejar exibir ou não

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
<?php
  $horaatual = time() % 86400;
  $horade    = 18 * 60 * 60;
  $horaate   = 24 * 60 * 60 - 1; // Tirei um pra ficar 23:59:59

  if ($horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate) {
?>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <h1>aqui vai o conteudo da div</h1>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Ou poderiam muito bem ser strings:

```
<?php
  $horaatual = date('H:i:s' ); // use gmdate() para UTC
  $horade    = '18:00:00';
  $horaate   = '23:59:59';

  if ($horaatual >= $horade and $horaatual <= $horaate) {
?>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <h1>aqui vai o conteudo da div</h1>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Há quem faça essa loucura aqui, mas é complicação desnecessária e desperdício de recursos:

```
$horaatual = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
```

Notar três coisas importantes:

- Se o minuto a menos fizer falta, ajuste o `time()` pra `( time() + 1 )` e desconte no resto;
- Se quiser hora local, ajuste o `time()` com o fuso desejado, em segundos, e/ou ajuste a Timezone do servidor corretamente para a região do teste;
- Tem muitas outras maneiras de fazer, o importante é a lógica. Tem funções diversas de data e hora no manual.

Comment: No $horaatual e hora ate coloco 18:00, ou so 18 ?

Comment: Qual código devo usar ? tipo, um exemplo, um código pronto

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente, Obrigado!