# php exibir texto conforme horário

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma página de portfólio.

E estou com essa dúvida, se quando a pessoa acessar meu site a noite, exibir a mensagem de boa noite na tela.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/287647/99718

Answer (score 2):

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) - configura o fuso horário padrão utilizado por todas as funções de data e hora em um script

[date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) — Formata a data e a hora local

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$hour = date('H');

    if($hour >= 6 && $hour < 12) {
        echo "bom dia";
    }else if($hour >= 12 && $hour < 18) {
        echo "boa tarde";
    }else if($hour >= 18 && $hour < 24) {
        echo "boa noite";
    } else {
        echo "vai dormir";
    }
```

Veja funcionando em [PHP Sandbox, test PHP online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f84b80eea24e2c5f2f2f7b1175a0236df3397c3)

Comment: Qual é a utilidade de `$hour = (int)$hour;`?